# SQL JOIN query needs over 15s to run

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty big SQL query to get data from multiple database tables. I use the `ON` condition to check if the guild_ids are always the same and in some cases, he check's for an user_id too.

That is my query:

```
SELECT
    SUM( f.guild_id = 787672220503244800 AND f.winner_id LIKE '%841827102331240468%' ) AS guild_winner,
    SUM( f.winner_id LIKE '%841827102331240468%' ) AS win_sum,
    m.message_count,
    r.bypass_role_id,
    i.real_count,
    i.total_count,
    i.bonus_count,
    i.left_count 
FROM
    guild_finished_giveaways AS f
    JOIN guild_message_count AS m
    JOIN guild_role_settings AS r
    JOIN guild_invite_count AS i ON m.guild_id = f.guild_id 
    AND m.user_id = 841827102331240468 
    AND r.guild_id = f.guild_id 
    AND i.guild_id = f.guild_id 
    AND i.user_id = m.user_id
```

But it runs pretty slow, with over 15s. I can't see why it needs so long.

I figured out that if I remove the "guild_invite_count" JOIN, it's pretty fast again. Do I have some simple error here that I don't see? Or what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you use index ?

Comment: I have no clue about indexes. I thought that `guild_id` would be something like that.

Comment: No `GROUP BY` needed?

Comment: Your JOIN chain is a bit backwards. Why don't you have a separate ON for each JOIN?

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN and table definitions. 
Also - I'd love to see sample data and expected results. Your syntax looks unconventional, and I'm not sure it's doing what you think it is.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly the "LIKE" clause with the leading wild card.

Comment: Joins and aggregation can be a bit tricky. Do you get another result of you aggregate in a subqeury _before_ joining?

Comment: Is f.winner_id a character/varchar column, but m.user_id an integer/numeric column? How come?

Comment: winner_id is a varchar column, because it can contain multiple ids in that format: "123 123 123"

Comment: As previously requested, please add the EXPLAIN output for your query and your table definitions to your question. The output of `SHOW INDEX FROM tbl` for each table would also be helpful. The fact that you can execute this query without receiving an error suggests you have [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) disabled, which is a bad idea as it allows nondeterministic queries.

Comment: Storing serialised data (space separated user_ids) in your `f.winner_id` column is a really bad idea. You should split them off into their own junction table.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  I assume the ids are `BIGINT UNSIGNED`?  Do you really need the `LIKE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `JOIN` expression needs it's own `ON`. Don't wait until the end for this. As it was, the server was forced to build up a cartesian product of all those tables before narrowing them down again, and I'm surprised the query ran at all (I'd expect a syntax error for missing `ON` clauses).

```
FROM guild_finished_giveaways AS f
  JOIN guild_message_count AS m ON m.guild_id = f.guild_id 
  JOIN guild_role_settings AS r ON r.guild_id = f.guild_id
  JOIN guild_invite_count AS i ON i.guild_id = f.guild_id 
      AND i.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE m.user_id = 841827102331240468
```

It's also more than a little odd to use `SUM()` or any other aggregate function in the same query as non-aggregated values without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: As much as I agree that the join criteria should be in the associated on clause, it is incorrect to suggest that the server will produce a cartesian product with OP's query. The optimiser will deal with the incorrectly placed criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `InnoDB`?

Does every table have a `PRIMARY KEY`?

These *may* help:

```
m:  PRIMARY KEY(user_id)  -- assuming that is unique in that table
f:  INDEX(guild_id,  winner_id)
r:  INDEX(guild_id,  bypass_role_id)
i:  INDEX(user_id,)
```

It looks like some tables should not be separate -- perhaps r,i,f could be combined?  (I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to say more.)

Do *NOT* have a commalist in `winner_id`.  Instead have another table with one row per winner per game (or whatever it is a winner of).  Perhaps just to columns like a [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) mapping table.

Noting that the execution is likely to start with `m` and then go next to `i` let's improve on Joel's suggestion:

```
FROM   guild_message_count      AS m
  JOIN guild_invite_count       AS i ON i.user_id  = m.user_id
  JOIN guild_finished_giveaways AS f ON f.guild_id = m.guild_id 
  JOIN guild_role_settings      AS r ON r.guild_id = m.guild_id
WHERE m.user_id = 841827102331240468
```

Note that 3 tables are joined on `guild_id`; but only 2 `=` are needed.

`SUM` without `GROUP BY` sums up the entire resultset (after JOINing).  But you have 6 non-aggregates, so you need to `GROUP BY` all 6.

But that may lead to grossly inflated sums.  Maybe you need to do the aggregation just over `f` *first* since that is where you are summing.  Then JOIN to the rest??